# I am unable to use these commands on my personal network

Tags: networking, home-networking, cmd.exe

```
Windows 8.1
C:\Users\Rajat>net view/all
The syntax of this command is:

NET
    [ ACCOUNTS | COMPUTER | CONFIG | CONTINUE | FILE | GROUP | HELP |
      HELPMSG | LOCALGROUP | PAUSE | SESSION | SHARE | START |
      STATISTICS | STOP | TIME | USE | USER | VIEW ]

C:\Users\Rajat>net view
System error 6118 has occurred.

The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available

C:\Users\Rajat>getmac /s list
ERROR: The RPC server is unavailable.
```

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Your network is **not** hacked.  Your system installation just appears to be corrupt.

Comment: did you google "System error 6118 has occurred"  plenty of answers there

Comment: UDP    192.168.209.1:138      *:*                                    4
 UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    5540
 UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    5540
 UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                                    4328
 UDP    [::]:50971             *:*                                    5540
 UDP    [::]:61372             *:*                                    4328

Comment: i am getting these udp.. are udp normal on a home network

Comment: **They are not malicious.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using those commands incorrectly.

Ensure you're typing and spacing things properly, ie: `net view/all` should be `net view /all`.

`getmac /s list` is requesting the MAC addresses from a server named "list", which I'm pretty sure is not your intention. For the local computer use just `getmac`.

Using `/?` after your command will show you proper usage.  i.e.: `getmac /?`

For more information on understanding the command-line help syntax, perhaps check out this article: [How to Read Windows Command Line Syntax](https://www.maketecheasier.com/read-windows-command-line-syntax/)

The most usual cause for "System error 6118 has occurred" when using `net view` is documented by Microsoft: [Error 6118: "The List of Servers for This Workgroup..."](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/139910).

Comment: but why rpc is unavailable

Comment: As I said, it's because you used the command to request a list of MAC addresses from a server (`/s`) named "list". A computer named "list" doesn't exist, so it's RPC server is not available (since it does not exist).

Comment: Can you please tell about these udp process also?

Comment: Post it as a separate question.  Except I recommend researching it thoroughly before hand, and include in your new question what you've already researched, tried, and what the results were.  Otherwise you'll just keep receiving down-votes for a lack of research effort.